# Any trick to darken the Linear Gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

```css
body{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff6a00, #ee0979);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff6a00, #ee0979);
}
```

/* The code above is for linear-gradient, and I want to darken it */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a black background-color and you apply a darken blending mode

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff6a00, #ee0979);
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
```